# php detecting if user is offline using setinterval?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i'm creating an online/offline system using PHP.

When user is logged in sessions are set and user is considered online and I run a set interval function that logs time(); into my database every 10 seconds.

```html
setInterval(function(){

//update time every 10 seconds
$.get("timeupdate.php");

}, 10000);
```

I need some direction please in my next stage when I have to detect when the user is offline and I am slightly confused.

Do I run an if else statement?

```
$time = time();
$time2 = $row['time_update'] -> last updated time in my database
if($time > $time2 + 20) {
    echo "user is offline";
}
```

because of the 10 second setinterval if `$time` ( the current unix timestamp) is greater than the last updated unix timestamp then user is offline.

am I right? and how would I go about implementing this display offline file?

Comment: when A user logs in, his login time is updated, and the time runs untill he logs out or closes the browser, and time is automatically updated when he refreshes or reloades pages. its in my mind

Answer (score 0):

Why implement the logic in PHP when the data in your database? If you're using MySQL date times....

```
SELECT last_seen_seconds_ago
, IF($MAXINTERVAL*1.05>last_seen_seconds_ago, 1, 0) AS status
FROM (
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_update) 
   AS last_seen_seconds_ago 
FROM yourtable
WHERE user='$user') ilv
```

(allows a 5% variance)